# Get float of UnitIlluminance from ios

Tags: ios, swift, sensors, luminance

I want the luminance value of iPhone. In Android we can get it using Type_Light as given here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment

I want the same for iOS. I want the value like 80.0 or 454.0 whatever the luminance is. Is there any way I can get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android you can access the data from the light sensor. Unfortunately on iOS there is no access to the light sensor. An Apple developers relations developer responded to a similar question here:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81806

You could try using the camera, and getting the light intensity from there, but it will not be nearly or close to as accurate as the data from the light sensor.

Comment: Thanks @Chrystian. Though whoever downvoted the question must have answered the question themselves lol